# getting warning in erlang about node names on function restart

Tags: eclipse, erlang, nodes, application-restart

I am following the book "Learn me some Erlang".  I have installed eclipse on my windows machine in order to run the scripts, and I came across an error on runtime:

```
** exception error: bad argument
```

Apparently this error is caused by nodes having the same name on repeated restarts within the `judge2` function, third line.

However, I am not sure how to correct the problem.

Here is my code:

```
start_critic2() ->
    spawn(?MODULE, restarter, []).

restarter() ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, critic, []),
    receive
        {'EXIT', Pid, normal} -> % not a crash
            ok;
        {'EXIT', Pid, shutdown} -> % manual termination, not a crash
            ok;
        {'EXIT', Pid, _} ->
            restarter()
    end.

judge2(Band, Album) ->
    Ref = make_ref(),
    critic ! {self(), Ref, {Band, Album}},
    receive
        {Ref, Criticism} -> Criticism
    after 2000 ->
            timeout
    end.

critic2() ->
    receive
        {From, Ref, {"Rage Against the Turing Machine", "Unit Testify"}} ->
            From ! {Ref, "They are great!"};
        {From, Ref, {"System of a Downtime", "Memoize"}} ->
            From ! {Ref, "They're not Johnny Crash but they're good."};
        {From, Ref, {"Johnny Crash", "The Token Ring of Fire"}} ->
            From ! {Ref, "Simply incredible."};
        {From, Ref, {_Band, _Album}} ->
            From ! {Ref, "They are terrible!"}
    end,
    critic2().
```

Comment: if anyone has the same confusion you should change critic to critic2 in the judge2 function. The make_ref() function in judge2 is suppose to create unique nodes as the message are received from critic2. Sorry I have just started learning this language 3 days ago.

Comment: on repeated restarts which the spawn_link() should also contain critic2 with this line below "register(critic, Pid)",

Comment: Unfortunately your question and code are not clear and are hard to understand, which is likely why nobody has answered it. I suspect your error is due to the process registered as `critic` dying and not being restarted, and then when you try to send a message to the process with that name, you get a `badarg` because there is no such process. Since you're new to Erlang, try adding some `io:format` calls into your code to print out some debugging messages to help you make sure the `critic` process is getting restarted as you think it should.

Comment: sorry I am new to the language so I am just getting familiar with the formatting.